# How can I ensure that all of my JavaScript functions return a value?

Tags: javascript, jslint

I've had numerous bugs happening just because of a missing `return` in a function. You see, when most of the code you write is in Ruby, it's easy to forget about explicit returns.

So I'd like to use something similar to JSlint (which I already use) to check that all functions return something. Yes, I think it's better to explicitly return something when it's not required than to hunt down missing returns.

So, are there any tools that would check for returns? Or maybe I can assert it in runtime in a simple manner?

Please don't suggest Coffeescript, I'm aware of its existence.

Comment: This is just a picture perfect reason to unit test your javascipt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JSUnit](https://github.com/pivotal/jsunit) example:

```
<script language="javascript" src="jsUnitCore.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
  function testWithValidArgs() {
      assertEquals("someFunction should return something", "Expected REturn Value", someFunction(2, 3));
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Favour [mocha](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha) or [jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) instead of jsunit

Answer (score 1):

Just add `return` consistently. But to be honest, JSlint is a VERY strict checking tool. You will never get errors if you're not returning values unless you're trying to define a variable using the response of a function, but in that case it's more than logic that you add a `return` statement.

However, if you're still dedicated to have a `return` statement in every function, you should add them from the start. There is no tool that adds them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any tools that will do this out of the box. But it would not be hard to write one.

Start by using [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) to parse your code into a syntax tree. Write a recursive function that examines all code, looking for function definitions. For every function you find, look at the last statement. If that one is not a return-statement, then print a warning.

Answer (score 0):

(Too long for comment.)

My problem with returning something when a function has no (meaningful) return value is that it's misleading, unless it returns `undefined`, which defeats the purpose.

If I see a `return`, I have to reason about the code both in the method and at the call site.

In the function I have to determine if it ever returns anything else, why it returns the value it does, etc. The only real way around this is to return a constant that makes it obvious the it's not *really* returning anything, it's just to satisfy a desire to return *something*.

At the call site, if a return value is ignored, I need to understand why, and if it's okay to do so. If I know every function returns something, I then have to check the function to see if it's returning that special value, or go through the above process.

I'd almost rather namespace my functions into `"function"` and `"method"` namespaces at that point as a differentiater. This would allow automated testing of each namespace to make sure that all functions return something useful, all methods specifically *don't*, and would provide a source-level clue as to which the caller should expect.